# Ruby on Rails access data through multiple joining tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have 5 tables (simplest reduction) with 3 tables in the middle.

```
       /   sample   \
      |              |
chart -   compound   -  results
      |              |
       \ run_method /
```

each chart has a sample, compound and run_method.

each result has a sample, compound and run_method.

I would like to get all the results that match the chart's 3 joins ...

what is the simplest way of doing this?

```
class Chart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sample, inverse_of: :charts
  belongs_to :compound, inverse_of: :charts
  belongs_to :run_method, inverse_of: :charts
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sample, inverse_of: :results
  belongs_to :compound, inverse_of: :results
  belongs_to :run_method, inverse_of: :results
end

class Sample < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results, inverse_of: :sample
  has_many :charts, inverse_of: :compound
end

etc.
```

I have tried to use Arel to get the data out:

```
chart = Chart.arel_table
results = Result.arel_table
run_method = RunMethod.arel_table
sample = Sample.arel_table
compound = Compound.arel_table

results_join = results.join(sample).on(results[:sample_id].eq(sample[:id]))
                      .join(compound).on(results[:compound_id].eq(compound[:id]))
                      .join(run_method).on(results[:run_method_id].eq(run_method[:id]))
                      .join(chart).on(chart[:sample_id].eq(sample[:id])
                                      .and(chart[:compound_id].eq(compound[:id]))
                                      .and(chart[:run_method_id].eq(run_method[:id])))
@allresults = Result.joins(results_join.join_sources)
  .where(chart[:id].eq(params[:id]))
```

and that gets the expected values, but now obviously doesn't actually use the ActiveRecord models, so misses any default scopes.

In the Chart model I have added:

```
has_many :results, -> { where('results.run_method_id = run_methods.id and results.compound_id = compounds.id') }, through: :sample
```

and I can get the data using:

```
Chart.joins(:run_method).joins(:compound).includes(:run_method).includes(:compound).joins(:results).includes(:results).first.results
```

but this still doesn't actually use the joins of the in between models (except samples).

is there a way of doing this nicerin ActiveRecord and models?

Comment: Did you not have any success doing it the regular way `Result.joins(:sample)...`?

Comment: The issue is more about how to get to the results from the chart, where it depends on matching all 3 in between tables:
`Chart.joins(sample: :results).joins(compound: :results).joins(run_method: :results).find(1)` for instance joins to 3 different copies of the "results" table.  If there was a way of using "through:" in the model with 3 different keys, I might be able to just join against it directly

Comment: I could use `chart=Chart.find(1); Results.joins(:sample).joins(:compound).joins(:run_method).where("samples.id = ? and run_method.id = ? and compound.id = ?', [chart.sample_id, chart.run_method_id, chart.compound_id])` ... but I really don't think that simplifies the solution.  What I would like is a "chart.results" equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually created a def calling to the Result object inside the Chart model:

in chart.rb:

```
def results
  Result.where(compound: compound, run_method: run_method, sample: sample)
end
```

it works, and is quick, and doesn't need huge amounts of Arel or remembering which minimum tables to include/join.

I didn't need a reverse of the "join", so I considered this to be safe.